# Line break in table

Tags: html, css, html-table, line-breaks

My web page is divided into two columns, left and right. In the right column I have a table that is quite long horizontal, so it doesn't fit on the screen (see illustration 3 below). The only thing I can think of is to split the table into to lines (see illustration 2 below).

Therefore I want a line break in the middle of this table, after the 4th *th* and *td*.

Splitting with a tr after the 5th th and td cell doesn't do the trick because it will stack up the ths under each other and under them the tds (see illustration 1 below).

#### Illustration 1:

```
th1 th2 th3 th4
th5 th6 th7 th8
td1 td2 td3 td4 <- tds
td5 td6 td7 td8 <- tds
```

#### Illustration 2 (what I want):

```
th1 th2 th3 th4
td1 td2 td3 td4 <- tds

th5 th6 th7 th8
td5 td6 td7 td8 <- tds
```

#### Illustration 3:

**The problem:**

```
---------------------------------------------
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :   Header1  Header2   Header3   Header4
|                    :     1        12      | 40         5
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
---------------------------------------------
```

**Desired output:**

```
---------------------------------------------
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :   Header1  Header2   |
|                    :     1        12      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :   Header3   Header4  |
|                    :     40         5     |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
|                    :                      |
---------------------------------------------
```

Of course I could use two separate tables, but that won't work in my case by several reasons.

**The code:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 4</th> // Line break
            <th>Header 5</th>
            <th>Header 6</th>
            <th>Header 7</th>
            <th>Header 8</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Foo 1</td>
            <td>Foo 2</td>
            <td>Foo 3</td>
            <td>Foo 4</td> // Line break
            <td>Foo 5</td>
            <td>Foo 6</td>
            <td>Foo 7</td>
            <td>Foo 8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can that be achieved?

[Here's a fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/HV7BH/) <------- !

Comment: Why do you need this? What special meaning does the 4th/5th row has which requires this separation visually?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: The reason for me needing this is that I want the table to fit into my right col on my web page.

Comment: @Eric: Actually the only thing I've tried is trs. I don't have any more ideas. :/

Comment: So you want an HTML table that is not rendered as an HTML table. You should probably describe the desired rendering and present this as a CSS question.

Comment: What is the problem with 2 tables ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: I'm using a jQuery plugin that shows the data in the table as graphical charts. For all the data to be shown in one chart I must use only one table.

Comment: @holyredbeard, it is not possible while using the semantics of the `table`.. You would need multiple `thead`/`tbody` groups to do it, but that is invalid HTML. You could style some rows as the `thead` but then it would not be semantically what you want..

Answer (score 1):

Using divs with `float: left` something like so:

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="header">
        header 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        row 1, col 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        row 2, col 1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="header">
        header 2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        row 1, col 2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        row 2, col 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="header">
        header 3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        row 1, col 3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        row 2, col 3
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
.column>.header {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you mean I should split up the table nodes and put them inside the different divs?

Comment: @holyredbeard. Yes, instead of using a table (driven by rows) use divs  to build a table-structure driven by columns.

Comment: Ok, but if I get you right that means I won't be using a table at all? Unfortunately I need a table because I'm using a jQuery plugin that grabs the data from the table and creates a chart from it.

Comment: You can't do what you're asking for with a table. Consider building a hidden table for the chart plugin.

Comment: @holyredbeard. Don't forget to mark as correct if the answer was/is useful.

Comment: Don't worry, will do that after I've tried out the solution. :-)

Comment: i used this `<td>&nbsp;</td>`